# How does this nested list comprehension expression works?

Tags: python, list, boolean

I am having some trouble understanding the following nested list comprehension. What does the first 'True' do in this expression? How does the overall expression work?

```
#Use a nested list comprehension to find all of the numbers from 1-1000 that 
#are divisible by any single digit besides 1 (2-9)
# comprehension testing truth for divisibilty: [True for divisor in range(2,10) if number % divisor == 0]
results = [number for number in range(1,1001) if True in [True for divisor in range(2,10) if number % divisor == 0]]
#print(results)
```

Comment: Note that `True in [True for divisor in range(2,10) if number % divisor == 0]` would be more naturally written as `any(number % divisor == 0 for divisor in range(2,10))`.

Answer (score 1):

Start by examining the inner comprehension:

```
[True for divisor in range(2,10) if number % divisor == 0]
```

In English, this says that for all `divisor` in `range(2,10)`, if `divisor` evenly divides `number`, then `True` will be in the list. In other words, the list will consist of a number of `True` values equal to the number of divisors from 2 through 9. Thus, if nothing from 2 through 9 divides `number`, the list will be empty. To make this clearer, abstract this out in a function:

```
def hasSingleDigitDivisorList(number):
    return [True for divisor in range(2,10) if number % divisor == 0]
```

(Note that this abstraction is solely for the purposes of understanding the expression. Given how unwieldy the name is, it may not make sense to abstract this particular piece of code in production.)

Next, substitute the function in for the list comprehension in the original expression:

```
results = [number for number in range(1,1001) if True in hasSingleDigitDivisorList(number)]
```

That the list is empty when there are no divisors is the important point, as the test `True in [...]` will fail if and only if the list is empty. In other words, the `True in ...` expression tests whether there are any divisors from 2 through 9. Turn this into a function:

```
def hasSingleDigitDivisor(number):
    return True in hasSingleDigitDivisorList(number)
```

(`hasSingleDigitDivisor` makes more sense as a functional unit than `hasSingleDigitDivisorList`, so you might actually use it in a project.)

Then substitute this new function into the overall expression:

```
results = [number for number in range(1,1001) if hasSingleDigitDivisor(number)]
```

In English, this expression collects all numbers from 1 through 1000 if they have a (non-unity) single digit divisor, which matches the comment above the snippet:

```
#... all of the numbers from 1-1000 that 
#are divisible by any single digit besides 1
```

Comment: `if True in [True for divisor in range(2,10) if number % divisor == 0]` reads  better as `if any(number % divisor == 0 for divisor in range(2,10))`